# point to article without having a menu link

Tags: joomla

I work with Joomla for some time but I have only little question. How can I point to an article without first make a link of it in a menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean link?  The dirty way to do it is you can pull the id and the title out of the url when you are editing it and then get creative with your link to reconstruct a url (by using a link you already know about) that the user will need to get to the article.

Does that make sense?

Comment: That's what I thought about too, good thought. I just stumbeled on this too :) Maybe you can use it also.  http://j.l33p.com/linkr

Comment: Great find, that's something that should have been included in the CMS by defualt.  That's definitely a better solution than what I suggested :)

Answer (score 2):

Also, the JCE Editor has a button where you can link to any article and sidestep the menu system: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/88/details

Comment: This is the easiest and fastest solution by far, good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is quite different:

1. First create some menu with you will never use, unless you already need any category to be browsed. The point is: you need to have links to category with will be the same as category alias, and if any category is subcategory add parent category as parent menu position.
2. Categories has `path` in database, this path is: `parent-alias/other-parent-alias/more-parents/category-alias` now, if you have done first step you should be able to get to category using it `path` data (function below).
3. Use sql query to get that path, and other function to make article `slug`

### this is code for 2 functions that should help you

```
/**
* $art si article object
*/
function articleLink(&$art){
    // create slug
    $link = $art->id.'-'.$art->alias;

    // get category link (path)
    $cat_link = categoryLinkFromArticle($art);
    $link = $cat_link.'/'.$link;
    return $link;
}


function categoryLinkFromArticle(&$art){
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM #__categories cat WHERE cat.id='$art->catid'");
    $cat = $db->loadObject();

    $link = $cat->path;
    return $link;
}
```

Typical usage

```
<?php foreach ($articles as $item) :  ?>
    <?php $link = articleLink($item); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" ><?php echo $item->title; ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```